# How to extract character component and numeric component from a variable and mix these components in other one

Tags: r

I am having problems to separate a special content from a variable in a data frame. The structure of my data frame is like this:

```
ID   Code    Mixture
001  101ABC    BD
002  021DPA    AA
003  FCA123    IO
```

My problem is with `code` variable it has a part that is numeric and a part that is character, I was trying to create something like this:

```
ID   Code    Mixture  v1   v2   V3
001  101ABC    BD     101  ABC  BDABC
002  021DPA    AA     021  DPA  AADPA
003  FCA123    IO     123  FCA  IOFCA
```

I want to create three new variables `v1`, `v2` and `v3`. `v1` is the numeric part of `Code`, `v2` is the character part from `Code` and `V3` is the link between `Mixture` and `v2`. Is there any command in R to create this. Thanks a lot of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract part of a string, use a regular expression: in R, type `help(regex)` and `help(grep)` for instructions.

```
> test=data.frame(ID=1:3,Code=c("101ABC","021DPA","FCA123"),Mixture=c("BD","AA","IO"))
> test$v1=gsub("[A-Z]*","",test$Code) # this returns the Code column with capital letters removed
> test$v2=gsub("[0-9]*","",test$Code)
> test$v3=paste(test$Mixture,test$v2,sep="")
> print(test)
  ID   Code Mixture  v1  v2    v3
1  1 101ABC      BD 101 ABC BDABC
2  2 021DPA      AA 021 DPA AADPA
3  3 FCA123      IO 123 FCA IOFCA
```

(There's probably a neater solution using the [stringr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html) package, but I haven't used stringr myself.)